How can I change the color of SVG in QML
I have a QML control to show a .svg picture. And I hope the color of the .svg fit my userdefined theme. But I don't konw how to change the color of the svg.
I have a Image control like is, but there is no color property for me. How can I do?
Image {
    id: icon
    anchors{
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
        right: parent.right
    }
    width: height
        source: "../Image/BxChevronDown.svg"
}


Does this answer your question? Need to change color of an SVG Image in QML   (you should have done research, see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+can+I+change+the+color+of+SVG+in+QML )

I have got the answer: The ColorImage should be used
ColorImage {
        id: icon
        anchors{
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
            right: parent.right
        }
        width: height
        source: "../Image/BxChevronDown.svg"
        color: theme.themeColor0
    }

picture
